# Should I move a dimension attribute to it's own dimension?

Tags: ssis, ssas, etl, data-warehouse

The question I have below is hypothetical, I'm using SSAS:

Let's say I have a dimension (dim_Product) representing products I sell in a store, I have another dimension (dim_Employee) representing the company's employees and I have a fact table (fact_EmployeeSalesPerMonth) showing how many products each employee has sold for this month.

Now, lets say that each product has a category, and I have a requirement from a client to display this category data in a report which pulls data from the warehouse. Let's say the question my client is trying to answer is "What employees are best at selling what categories of what products?".

The category of product from the source system is set by using a drop down list of predefined values. Let's say that the pre-defined values are electronics and hardware. This category text is stored on the dim_Product dimension as a text column.

Now let's say that we add a third category of products (children toys) in our source system, which at the moment, contains no products. My client would like the report to show this category. It's obvious that I'm not bringing through this category data, since there are no products linked to it.

My question is, if this is the requirement. How would I store this data in the warehouse? Where would I store it?

I've considered moving the category data to it's own dimension and then having a category key on the fact table pointing to the category dimension, but I'm not sure this is correct. This means that any fact table I create in the future, that is linked to dim_Product, would need to be linked to the product dimension as well as the product category dimension and have keys pointing to both.

Answer (score 3):

You are addressing several things in your question, so let’s go it through step by step

**Product Category Dimension**

A product category is an example of a dimension hierarchy. The first thing I’d recommend is to store the product category  in the product dimension table as an additional attribute, possible with other attributes such as subcategory, super-category. You may define so a product hierarchy with several levels.
The obvious consequence of this design is that if you want to introduce a new category you need at least one (e.g. dummy) product. 
The fact table contains only the product ID.

**Reporting of Product Category**

If you report on a product level, i.e. with dimensions month, product, category you will need a “non existing” product to fill in the report, so the “dummy” product entry in the dimension table is justified.
To get the dimension entries without usage in the report you may either integrate it in the reporting query or made an additional query – “what was not used?”. Which is better depend on your mileage, in case that you considers product IDs in the fact table that are not defined in the dimension table too, you will end in a full outer join (which could affect the performance) so you could find the latter option (with extra query – product from the dimension table that does NOT EXISTS in the fact table) more flexible.

If you report often only on the category level (without a product), you may find useful to define a category table. Especially if the category has other attributes such as description it is more convenient to have it in a dedicated table that to recover it from the product dimension with a DISTINCT query.

**Storing the category ID in the Fact Table**

The driver for this decision is in the dynamic of you product hierarchy. If there are changes in the product categories over time this approach delivers out of the box history of the attribute. You are able after the re-assignment of the product category to report the “correct” category in which the product was sold. (But you may also report all sales with the new category, simple ignoring the entry from the fact table and taking the category from the product dimension). The point here is IMO not in the decision if there is a category dimension, but if it is required to maintain a history of the product attributed (here the catrogory).

So if you read my answer and summaries what I recommend, finding that for the topics

- Extra category dimension table
- Storing category key in fact table
- Outer join or extra query to find not used dimensions

the answer is *it depends* – you got it!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this one! Appreciate it! Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make product category as an standalone dimension only if it is frequently used without a product list. If it is not frequently used or if it is mostly used with product list together, then it would make sense to make it an attribute instead.

Standalone dimensions are generally faster(I saw 50% reduction in query times when such attributes are used) but also cost more space/load time.
I saw about 7% size increase in a very big cube we had per such new dimension.
I would avoid them if they are not frequently used. It is about finding the correct balance. In my case, I had 50+ such attributes in one of the dimension and that would have made the cube a lot larger and it is already a large cube anyway.

By the way, by making it a part of Product dimension, a query bringing products corresponding to a category can be resolved by using autoexists instead of fact retrieves.